# Padding for JQuery Mobile Simple Dialog

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm using [Simple Dialog 2](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/):

I have the dialog box below:

```
$('<div>').simpledialog2({
    mode: 'button',
    themeHeader: 'b',
    headerText: 'Confirm',
    headerClose: true,
    buttonPrompt: message,
    buttons : {
        'OK': {
            click: function () { 
                $.mobile.changePage(url, {changeHash: false});
            }
        },
        'Cancel': {
            click: function () { 

            },
            icon: "delete",
            theme: "c"
        }
    }
})
```

Screenshot:

[image]

I want to `text-align` the message to left and have some space from left and right side of the button. How can I achieve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Firebug or another developer tool to examine the CSS to manipulate...
[see docu](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/themes.html)

> **Overriding themes**
>
> The themes are meant as a solid starting point, but are meant to be
>   customized. Since everything is controlled by CSS, it's easy to use a
>   web inspector tool to identify the style properties you want to
>   modify. The set of of theme classes (global) and semantic structural
>   classes (widget-specific) added to elements provide a rich set of
>   possible selectors against which to target style overrides. We
>   recommend adding an external stylesheet to the head, placed after the
>   structure and theme stylesheet references, that contain all your style
>   overrides. This allows you to easily update to newer versions of the
>   library because overrides are kept separate from the library code.

Comment: i got it with `.ui-simpledialog-controls`. Thank you.

Comment: @JRGalia What do you mean you got it with `.ui-simpledialog-controls`. Can you provide an example?